# When using "AND" in where clause get error "argument must be type boolean"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Error:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying

```
SELECT 
    partno, 
    count(manufacturer) 
FROM 
    components 
WHERE 
    partno IN (SELECT partno FROM productions 
               WHERE 
                    year = 2005
                AND attr is NULL
              ) 
GROUP BY partno
UNION
SELECT 
    partno, 
    count(manufacturer) 
FROM components 
WHERE 
    partno IN (SELECT partno FROM productions 
               WHERE 
                   year = 2005
               AND attr is NULL
              ) 
GROUP BY partno
) 
AND (
        partno NOT IN (SELECT partno FROM components
    )
);
```

The part after the union is to include all partno from components that are not in productions (they should be counted as 0)

Comment: You have one closing bracket `)` wrong in the second part of the union (or you are missing an opening bracket before `year=2005`)

Comment: What is that second part of the `UNION` meant to be retrieving? If we remove suspicious brackets, we seem to end up asking for rows from `components` that don't exists in `components`. Which seems mildly problematic.

Comment: How is that problematic? The first part of the union doesn't count them.

Comment: I'll repeat again "rows from `components` that don't exist in `components`" - how will that ever be a non-empty set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one bracket too many (after the `attr IS NULL`) and you have an aggregate function (the `count` in the second part) without a `group by`. Do you mean this:

```
select partno, count(manufacturer) 
from components 
where partno in 
(
   select partno from productions where year=2005 and attr is NULL
) 
group by partno

UNION

select partno, count(manufacturer) 
from components 
where partno in 
(
    select partno from productions where year=2005 and attr is NULL
) 
AND partno not in (select partno from components)
group by partno;
```

Comment: Now it's saying components.partno must appear in group by clause.

Comment: This answer corrects your original query, but **the second `SELECT` statement does not add any information to the resultant rowset**: all rows returned by the second select exist in the first select, but then they are discarded, because the `UNION` operator removes duplicate rows. Just to be clear: this is not a problem of this answer, this is a problem of the original query.

Comment: @Celeritas: as Gerardo points out, we need your input to know what it is you are trying to get! My answer has, hopefully, corrected the syntax error, but not the logical one!